# Javascript setTimeout-recursion doesn't work with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, settimeout

The code below is for sliding a div inside another hidden overflow div (concept for future website).
The text box below the "next" and "previous" links is for indicating the x value.
With IE8 everything works just fine.

With Chrome and Firefox it seems to do the function only once (one step) both "next" and "prev", which means **setTimeout** doesn't run.

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var ie5 = (document.all && document.getElementById);
            var ns6 = (!document.all && document.getElementById);

            function next(startx, fadeStep, end){
                if(startx > end){
                    startx -= Math.round((1/Math.pow(fadeStep,0.6)));
                    if (startx < end) startx = end;
                    document.getElementById('lastname').value = startx + "px";
                    document.getElementById('test1').style.left = startx + "px";
                    fadeStep += 0.00035;
                    args = "next(" + startx + "," + fadeStep + "," + end + ")";
                    setTimeout(args, 20); 
                }
            }

            function prev(startx, fadeStep, end){
                if(startx < end){
                    startx += Math.round((1/Math.pow(fadeStep,0.6)));
                    if (startx > end) startx = end;
                    document.getElementById('lastname').value = startx + "px";
                    document.getElementById('test1').style.left = startx + "px";

                    setTimeout('prev(' + startx + ',' + (fadeStep+0.00035) + ',' + end + ')', 20);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:relative;width:570;height:78;overflow:hidden">
            <div id="test1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:1180;height:78">
                <img src="http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/7225/imageva.png" border=1>
                <img src="http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/5554/image2te.png" border=1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:900px;top:0px;width:800">
            <a href="#" onclick="next(0, 0.001, -570)">Next</a><br />
            <a href="#" onclick="prev(-570, 0.001, 0)">Previous</a></ br>
            <form><input type="text" id="lastname" value="gfgfg"/></form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: I think your code would be greatly simplified if you used something like jQuery.

Comment: Did you try passing actual functions instead of strings to setTimeout?  `setTimeout(function(){ next(startX, fadeStep, end);}, 20)`

Comment: I'm not having issue with either of those browsers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better way, in this case, to use setTimeout like the following:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { next(startx, fadeStep, end); } , delayInMiliseconds);
```

However, the lack of the "window." object prefix might be another cause of your functionality not working in these browsers.

If you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask.

As stated in the comments it would save a good deal of time to use jQuery.

Best regards,

Comment: " setTimeout(function(){ next(startX, fadeStep, end);}, 20)"
and "window.setTimeout(function(){ next(startX, fadeStep, end);}, 20)" also work great on IE8 but not in Chrome & FF. Maybe it because I'm trying it locally and some JS elements are blocked?

Comment: BTW is there a ready code for this in jquery? Never used it before

Comment: Yes. You can, for example, use the animate function of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thank you very much! Works in all browsers :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck with jQuery. I am sure it will save you a lot of time as it did for me :)